# BOX CSS - Difficulties with position

Tags: css

Use % layout responsive

HTML Source

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Top -->
<div id="top"> TOP</div>
<!-- Menu  MID LEFT -->
<div id="midleft"> Menu Meio Esquerda</div>
<!--MID-->
<div id="mid"> BANNER</div>
<!-- Back -->
<div id="back"> RordaPé </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Soruce

```
html, body {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
margin:0; height: 100%;
}

#top{
background-color: #bfb;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:18%
}
#midleft
{
background-color: #ddd; 
position: relative; 
width: 12%;
height: 65%;
padding: 1%;
padding-right: 2%;
}
#mid{
background-color: #ff9;
float: right;
width: 75%;
height: 35%
}
#back{
background-color: #bfb;
width: 100%;
height: 7%;
clear:both;
}
```

I need to make my layout like this!

[image: img]

I'm not able to do this Responsive Layout Mode.

Could someone send me link explaining Position BOX in CSS3?

Or should do another layout mode without BOX CSS?

Comment: What do you mean by "BOX CSS"? Everything in CSS uses the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). There is no alternative to the box model, and all CSS uses it.

Comment: Here are links to learn more about CSS [boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Boxes) and [changing the layout of elements on your page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Layout). And [more documentation about CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).